# Cannot read property 'updated' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I use `setApi(data.time);` in the fetch section I can normally do `console.log(api.updated);`, but why I can not do just like what I wrote in the code below?

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/currency-api-6tuh2)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [api, setApi] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setApi(data);
      });
  }, []);
  console.log(api.time.updated);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Currency Exchange</h1>
      {/* <p>Time: {api.time.updated}</p>
      <u>
        <li>Code: {api.bpi.USD.code}</li>
        <li>Rate: {api.bpi.USD.rate}</li>
      </u> */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (and get a badge). Your question lacks any attempt at solving this problem on your own. The idea is for you to try to get something to work and then come here with specific problems you are unable to resolve. Taking the tour and reading about [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center will provide all the information you need.

Comment: In addition to Randy's comment, can you include the code in the question instead of linking it? EDIT: Thanks for adding the code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your revised code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [api, setApi] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setApi(data);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Currency Exchange</h1>
      {api.time?.updated && <><p>Time: {api.time.updated}</p>
      <u>
        <li>Code: {api.bpi.USD.code}</li>
        <li>Rate: {api.bpi.USD.rate}</li>
      </u></>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Simple way to check and ensure the API resolved with the appropriate data, then show the designated information.

Note that there's a reason why you have .then for your API query - it takes time to come back. Your code was executing before the api state could be filled with the response.

With the logical && operator, there's a simple way to look at it with React and I use it all the time.

If I have a loader component or something I want to show only when the loading variable is true, I can do something like this:

```
{loading && <Loader />}
```

The code to the right of the && will ONLY run if the left side is true. Since it's AND, if the first part is false it doesn't matter what the other parts are and they're skipped.

Answer (score 1):

Before the request is complete `api` will be an empty object. `api.time` will then be `undefined`, and trying to access property `updated` on that will give rise to your error.

You could use the [logical AND `&&` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) to make sure `api.time` is set.

```js
const [api, setApi] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
  fetch("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      setApi(data);
    });
}, []);

console.log(api.time && api.time.updated);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a extra state to check loading data and display it when fetch done:

```js
export default function App() {
  //add loading to check api request and data to save result
  const [api, setApi] = useState({ loading: false, data: undefined });

  useEffect(() => {
    setApi({ loading: true });
    fetch("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setApi({ loading: false, data: data });
      });
  }, []);


  return (
    <>
      {!api.loading && api.data ? (//check if data is loaded
        <div className="App">
          <h1>Currency Exchange</h1>
          <p>Time: {api.data.time.updated}</p>
          <u>
            <li>Code: {api.data.bpi.USD.code}</li>
            <li>Rate: {api.data.bpi.USD.rate}</li>
          </u>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <>Loading data...</>//show a message while loading data(or <></> if want not display something)
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```